# AjaxControlToolkit ReorderList doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, drag-and-drop, ajaxcontroltoolkit, reorderlist

I need to use a drag & drop control to order a list. I would like to realise this with the ReorderList control from the AjaxControlToolkit. I've tried everything to get it work, but it won't. Everything goed well, like the filling of the list etc. But I can't use this control like it should be used. When the page is loaded, it displays a list, with a reordergrip on the left, but when i try to drag an item, it won't drag. It just stays in place. I've also tried other browser like IE9 & Firefox. Can someone please help me with this problem? I'm using ASP.NET/C# in Visual Studio 2010.

Thank you in advance!

ASPX:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="ajaxOrderedList">
            <asp:ReorderList runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ID="rlData" PostBackOnReorder="true" DragHandleAlignment="Left" ItemInsertLocation="Beginning" SortOrderField="Naam" AllowReorder="true">
                <DragHandleTemplate> 
                    <asp:Panel ID="dragHandle" runat="server" 
                        style="height: 20px; width: 20px; border: solid 1px black; background-color: Red; cursor: pointer;" 
                        Visible="<%# ShowDragHandle %>">
                        &nbsp;
                    </asp:Panel>
                    </DragHandleTemplate> 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="itemArea"> 
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNaam" runat="server" Text='<%#  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(Eval("Naam")))  %>' />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblFunctie" runat="server" Text='<%#  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToString(Eval("Functie")))  %>' />
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ReorderTemplate>
                    <div style="width: 300px; height: 20px; border: dotted 2px black;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </ReorderTemplate>
            </asp:ReorderList>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testdataConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [naam], [functie] FROM [personen]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [personen] WHERE [id] = @intID"
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [personen] ([naam], [functie]) VALUES (@strNaam, @strFunctie)"
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE [personen] SET [naam] = @strNaam, [functie] = @strFunctie WHERE [id] = @intID">
                <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="intID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="strNaam" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="srtFunctie" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="intID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="strNaam" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="srtFunctie" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
DataView MyDView = null; 

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ShowDragHandle = true;
            }
        }

        protected void ReorderList1_ItemReorder(object sender, ReorderListItemReorderEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowDragHandle = true;
        }

        protected Boolean ShowDragHandle { get; set; }


        protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //set theme
            this.Theme = "ServiceSuite";
        }
```

Image of not working Reorderlist (This is what I get if I try to drag an item!):

[image: This is what I get if I try to drag an item!]

Comment: [HERE](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ReorderList/ReorderList.aspx) This is what I need!

Comment: Having same problem. Got Any solutions for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your reorderlist properties

```
ClientIDMode="AutoID"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same problem when using an older version of the AjaxControlToolkit. It appears to be fixed in the current version (September 2012), which of course I can't use in my project. But maybe updating will help other folks.